# Sending mails from Sonar with SMTP and TLS not supported?

Tags: email, ssl, smtp, sonarqube

We would like violation notifications to be send from our Sonar via a SMTP Server (which is an Outlook 365 Server). This Server uses TLS to secure the connection. Sonar only offers me SSL secure connections.

When I try the SSL Option enabled I get the stack trace listed below.

**Is there way using Sonar and a SMTP Server using TLS?**

```
Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Exception reading response
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.readServerResponse(SMTPTransport.java:1611) ~[na:na]
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1369) ~[na:na]
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:412) ~[na:na]
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:310) ~[na:na]
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:169) ~[na:na]
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:118) ~[na:na]
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:118) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1232) ~[na:na]
    ... 250 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.handleUnknownRecord(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6]
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6]
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6]
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6]
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6]
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppInputStream.read(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6]
    at com.sun.mail.util.TraceInputStream.read(TraceInputStream.java:110) ~[na:na]
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6.0_43]
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6.0_43]
    at com.sun.mail.util.LineInputStream.readLine(LineInputStream.java:88) ~[na:na]
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.readServerResponse(SMTPTransport.java:1589) ~[na:na]
    ... 258 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Could you double check that the smtp port you provided is really a secured port ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 

We are using Outlook 365, which requires to connect with TLS only. We have other applications that use TLS secured connections with the same server configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Ticket created to support TLS : http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-4647.